# Oracle SQL: Sum Over Partition returns error in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case, partition

I have a larger `Select` statement which works fine until I include the following which returns the below error.
Using just the `Sum` part works too but I only need this for the first row of each AID which is why I used the Row Number here.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?
Is the problem maybe that Sum and Partition are referring to two different tables which I am joining in the Select ?

**My SQL (part of Select):**

```
, CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dp.SHIPPER_ID ORDER BY di.AID) = 1 THEN (SUM(di.SHIPPED_UNITS) OVER (PARTITION BY dp.SHIPPER_ID))
    ELSE '' 
END AS Gesamtmenge
```

**Error message:**

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
```

Many thanks in advance for any help,
Mike

Comment: Is `shipped_units` type number?

Comment: @RLOG: Yes, it is type number.

Comment: Use null instead of ''

Comment: @MiloBellano: Thanks so much - that works perfect ! If you post it as an answer I will accept this. :)

Comment: Happy to help! :) I have posted the answer if you want to accept it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As original column is integer, you can't pass a char so

```
, CASE 
  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dp.SHIPPER_ID ORDER BY di.AID) = 1 THEN 
 (SUM(di.SHIPPED_UNITS) OVER (PARTITION BY dp.SHIPPER_ID))
 ELSE NULL
END AS Gesamtmenge
```

Answer (score 1):

Error says all. You are using `''` which is essentially a char and not int.

```
, CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dp.SHIPPER_ID ORDER BY di.AID) = 1 THEN (SUM(di.SHIPPED_UNITS) OVER (PARTITION BY dp.SHIPPER_ID))
    ELSE NULL 
END AS Gesamtmenge
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works. Milo just posted this as well.

Comment: Good. I missed by 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as error message points out you can not mix different datatypes in CASE. For example this is wrong

```
select case when 1=1 then 2 else '' end from dual
```

Use `null` or 0 in `else` or convert `then` expression to string